# Random word generating stuck on the same word in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Hey guys I'm new to PHP and I wanted to make a page that gets a random word from a text file and here is the code:

```
<?php
$chosen="Word";
function get(){
    $lines= file ("words.txt");
    $words=count($lines);
    $chosen=$lines[rand(0 ,$words - 1)];
    return $chosen;
}
?>
```

And then I call it from JS:

```
word = <?php echo json_encode(get()); ?>;
document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = word
```

The problem I get is the first time the function returns a random word, but after that it's the exact same word over and over.

Comment: `file` will return an array of lines, not words. Make sure that your file have each word on a separate line

Comment: I agree with @RomanPerekhrest and your code looks syntactically correct.

Comment: I think you may have fallen into a common misunderstanding of how PHP and JS communicate. The way you've written it here, it sounds like you're expecting the JS code to be able to call the PHP function directly, but that's not how it works. Your browser sends a request to the server, which runs the PHP once and sends a result back. If that result contains JS, the browser will then run what the PHP returned, but by the time it's doing that, your PHP code has finished completely.

Comment: @IMSoP I thought so. anyway I can get a new word without refreshing the page?

Comment: Yes, use Ajax to call the PHP random word function

Comment: Either the whole list of words has to be sent to the browser, or the browser needs to request a new word from the server. Luckily, you can request a URL from the server without reloading the whole page; read up on "AJAX". (If there isn't a Reference question this could be closed as a duplicate of, there really should be...)

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm gonna start looking AJAX up and altering the code.

Answer (score 1):

If PHP is capable of generating your JS code and you prefer to not get messy with AJAX then try this:

**index.php**

```
<script>
// Get PHP to create a JS array
var all_words = <?php echo json_encode(file("words.txt")); ?>;

// Create a JS function to fetch a random word
function get_word(){
    // Don't go out of bounds and return a word
    return all_words[Math.floor((Math.random() * (all_words.length - 1)) + 1)];
}

// Call the function and enjoy :)
document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = get_word();
</script>
```

Comment: I intend to make the words.txt file big (around 10000 words) and I don't want the user side to be script to be buggy.

Comment: @AFTX-Star Please define "buggy". What errors are you expecting? If 10,000 words average 6 characters (6 bytes) then you are serving up a mere 60,000 bytes or 60 KB of words; smaller than most image files.

Comment: I wanna host the script on my computer, and since my upload speed is low I don't think that's a good idea.